# Locally discrete and globally discrete set in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

My aim is about constructing an entire function with prescribed set of zeros in $\mathbb{C}$. The question is *what set should we take*? Certainly we can't take $\{1,1/2,1/3,\cdots\}$. Can we take $\{1, 1+1/2, 1+1/2+1/3,\cdots\}$ (I don't know)?

Then I thought, we should take discrete subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Here I caused some problem. Discrete in what sense? locally or globally?

A subset $S\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is said to be locally discrete if given $x\in S$, there exists open ball $B_x$ such that $S\cap B_x=\{x\}$.

A set $S$ is said to be globally discrete if there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(s,\epsilon)\cap S=\{s\}$ for every $s\in S$. In other words, we can put balls of fixed radius around each point of $S$ in such a way that no ball contains two points of $S$.

**Question:** The zero set of an entire function is locally discrete or globally discrete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of zeroes of an entire function is generally only locally discrete.  For instance, consider $f(z)=\sin z^2$.  This has zeroes at $\sqrt{n\pi}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and these are getting closer and closer together as $n$ gets large.

What you do need, however, is for $S$ to not just be discrete but closed; this is why $\{1,1/2,1/3,\cdots\}$ doesn't work.  Indeed, the zero set of any continuous function must be closed.  An infinite discrete closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$ must be a sequence of points going to $\infty$ (by compactness, if you had infinitely many points in any bounded set, they would have to accumulate somewhere).

In fact, a famous [theorem of Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#Existence_of_entire_function_with_specified_zeroes) says that if $S$ is any closed discrete subset of $\mathbb{C}$, then there is an entire function that vanished exactly on the set $S$.